# JavaFX disable touch / gestures

Tags: javafx, touch, gesture

We are getting lots of touch exceptions in production on Windows 8 tablets. Some of them cause the application to become irresponsive.

Some of the errors are:

```
java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many touch points reported

java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.touchEventBegin(Scene$ScenePeerListener.java) ~[jfxrt.jar:na]
```

There are a number of issues open on the javafx jira but mostly scheduled to be resolved in java 9

Is there a way to completely ignore touch / gestures in javafx and simply take taps as left mouse clicks as if it was a swing application?

Comment: Maybe you should update your java to the newest Update. 
I don't think that you can disable the Touch "native" stuff.

Comment: Yes, I reported it via the javafx jira (now jbs) and it got resolved in u60. The JavaFX team at Oracle seems to be very cooperative.